# CKEditor not working when the site is depoyed (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, localhost, ckeditor, hosting

CKEditor not working when the site is deployed(000webhost). It works fine in localhost.
I included CDN in the header

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/28.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and I used it in a form

```
 <div class="form-group">
         <label for="post_content">Post Content</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="post_content" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>



 <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );

    </script>
```

Comment: What is the error shown in the deployed site? Did you check the developer console?

Comment: Yes I have checked but there's nothing just textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is looking proper. Also it is working deployed server. But there might issue of loading cdn library. Please check it is loaded correctly.

```html
<div class="form-group">
         <label for="post_content">Post Content</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="post_content" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/28.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>

  ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );

</script>
```